# what this javascript is for?

Tags: javascript

I actually quite often bump into these:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19148109-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

but what is it for?

Comment: They are watching you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearance of *google-analytics.com* in the source rather gives the game away. It is for tracking people.

Comment: But why I should use this code instead of just using google analytics web app?

Comment: Because the web app is just a report viewer. Google can't make reports unless it gets data to make them with.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, this is a Google Analytics track code, allows the webmaster to track the visits with Google Analytics.

More info here: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/home.html

Answer (score 1):

That is the [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) tracking code used to track your visitors.